# Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am currently trying to load a .obj model into my three.js project. I feel like I have all the code correct becasuse my code compiles without any errors, but when I go to Google Chrome's console it is giving me this error. [image].

mainpage.html

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVOeN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVOeN.png)]

mainpage.js

[image]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code int he question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<body>

  <script src = "../node_modules/three/build/three.js"></script> 
    <script type = "module" src = "../public/mainpage.js"></script>

</body>
```

To ->

```
<body>

  <script src = "../node_modules/three/build/three.js"></script> 

    <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

    <script type = "module" src = "../public/mainpage.js"></script>

</body>
```

Basically, you're adding an Import Map.
I'm not sure however if this code that I just typed, will fix your problem since you just sent screenshots of the code, instead of the actual code.
For this reason, i'll be linking you a website that explains more about Import Maps and once again the link that @Rabbid76 commented, please also take a look at that one.

[ImportMaps](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/import-maps/)

[Please read this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: This Worked! Thank you very much for your help. You are a legend!
I must make sure that the pathing is correct.

Comment: No problem at all! If you would mind, could you accept this reaction as answer so that other people will directly see that your question got answered correctly. [How to accept an aswer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding

```
<script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
            }
        }
    </script>
```

"three" is the word that I made up. it can be anything, but I highly recommend that you choose wise words to improve the readability of your code. You must use that word when you are importing something into your JS file. 

"../build/three.module.js" is the path where in my case "three" is located at.


please let me know if I am wrong.